# How to trigger a new view when MPMoviePlayer stops playing?

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm new to iOS programming, and although I understand ObjC, It seems to me there is a lack of fundamental iOS programming knowledge. I'm doing the project for iPad where I need to show videos in fullscreen and some additional information on separate views (so information is partially in video format and partially in text/image). 
I ended up being able to only show video. That's pretty much it so far. So I will appreciate any advice. I don't need a tutorial. Just a hint on where and what to read to grasp a concept.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to register for MPMoviePlayer notifications. See "Movie Player Notifications" in the documentation for MPMoviePlayerController.

For displaying a new view either use UINavigationController (you can just use the navigation app template to start) or use presentModalViewController, or just fade in a new view with the supplemental info.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen some sort of didFinishPlaying notification message, however I think I have a problem with understanding how to push new view. I ended up reading the core animation framework guide just for sliding in the new view. I guess there is a more high level way.

Comment: see my edits for view handling.  core animation is not the answer for that.